# In standard set theory is a statement containing both a union and intersection but no parentheses disallowed?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, logic, convention

Most discussions of set theory with which I am familiar assign equal operator precedence to  $\cap$ and $\cup$.  This may sound like a ridiculous question, but I never thought about, nor do I recall encountering a formal rule regarding expressions of the form $\mathcal{F}=\mathcal{A}\cap\mathcal{B}\cup\mathcal{C}.$

Clearly $\mathcal{D}=\mathcal{A}\cap\left(\mathcal{B}\cup\mathcal{C}\right)$ is not equivalent to $\mathcal{E}=\left(\mathcal{A}\cap\mathcal{B}\right)\cup\mathcal{C}.$  The set $\mathcal{D}$ is necessarily a subset of $\mathcal{A};$ whereas $\mathcal{E}$ may contain an element of $\mathcal{C}$ which is not an element of $\mathcal{A}.$  So $\mathcal{E}$ is not necessarily a subset of  $\mathcal{A}.$

I found myself confused while attempting Exercise 1-5.7(B) of Stoll's *Set Theory and Logic*, and finally realized that much of that confusion may be related to not having a formal rule for how to deal with the possibility of encountering an expression of the form of $\mathcal{F}.$

I haven't attempted to prove the proposition, but it seems evident that any statement using parentheses to preclude such ambiguity will always transform into another such statement when the rules of manipulation are correctly followed.

But what are we to do with an expression such as $\mathcal{F}?$  Reject it as logically ambiguous, and thus invalid?  That seems to be the necessary choice.  Is this correct?

Comment: Writing something like $A\cap B\cup C$ is simply daft.

Comment: There's another possibility, which is to "read left to right" (or right to left), i.e., when operations have equal precedence, you perform them in the order you encounter them. That at least assigns a meaning to your F, although a wise author will probably use parens to make things easier for the reader.

Comment: @JohnHughes The exercise is to prove a general theorem about the structure of set theoretical expressions.  I can't rely on the kindness or wisdom of a particular author.  I don't recall having encountered a left-precedence rule in set theoretical literature.  If such a rule were asserted, then any such statement could be transformed into an equivalent one using parentheses.

Comment: What's the definition of "set theoretical expressions" ? Usually, if an inductive definition is given for a set of formulas including binary operation symbols, parentheses are part of the definition so that ambiguous formulas such as the one you wrote are not part of the formal language (but rather are abbreviations we humans use, along with priority rules to resolve the ambiguity)

Comment: Is that the exercise about transforming any formula in $X$ with righthand side $\varnothing$? Bob is assuming that the formula is unambiguously parenthesized, so you needn’t worry about expressions like $A\cap B\cup C$.

Comment: @Ned: This is very early in the book, and Bob doesn’t give a formal definition. Much later in the book he does define well-formed formulas for propositional logic, and there he’s careful to do so in a way that makes them fully parenthesized.

Comment: "then any such statement could be transformed into an equivalent one using parentheses": well, yes. That's the *point* of having a disambiguating rule. I wasn't saying that you should *assume* the left-to-right-parsing rule, merely that such a rule makes such expressions meaningful, so that if the author had included it somewhere, you could proceed. Apparently he didn't. If an author is indeed making hidden assumptions in problems for the reader, I would, as a reader, start to question whether I was reading the right book. It may have other merits that outweigh this problem, of course.

Comment: To the OP, it might help if you said what this exercise you're looking at is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to either reject it as ill-formed, or have in your system a rule assigning "$\cup$" and "$\cap$" unequal priorities. Really, though, this latter amounts to viewing "$A\cup B\cap C$" and similar expressions as *abbreviations for* expressions with parentheses placed appropriately. So there's no actual need to allow expressions like that at all, and I can't think why one would want to.

In particular, if you prove some logical result about all expressions which do involve parentheses as usual, it will also apply to expressions like "$A\cup B\cap C$" in the presence of an appropriate priority rule. I suspect that Stolle's exercise is working in a system where "$A\cup B\cap C$" is ill-formed, but there will be an analogue of the exercise which will work in any modification of that system to allow things like "$A\cup B\cap C$." So it won't make a substantive difference.

Comment: I think it is very useful to be able to write $2+3\times 4$.

Comment: @Ruy Fine - do you think it's ever useful to be able to write $A\cup B\cap C$? Just because in one context having unequal priorities is helpful doesn't mean that it's helpful in a different context. One big difference between the two, at least for me, is that there is no "symmetry" between $+$ and $\times$ like there is between $\cup$ and $\cap$. E.g. distributivity only works one way for $+/\times$ while we get both distributive laws for $\cup/\cap$. In an asymmetric context, a priority distinction feels less arbitrary.

Comment: For example, we can observe that $(a\times b)+c$ can't be broken down further while $a\times (b+c)$ can, and so it makes sense to say that "$a\times b+c$" should refer to the one which can't be further broken down. Another difference is about cognitive complexity. Since students see arithmetic operations long before they see set-theoretic ones, they're more comfortable distinguishing between $a\times (b+c)$ and $(a\times b)+c$ than they are between $A\cup (B\cap C)$ and $(A\cup B)\cap C$. So ambiguous notation feels more dangerous in the latter context than in the former context.

Comment: I agree that a convention would be less useful here but, at least in computer science, people have taken the time to set things straight: https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence

Comment: @Ruy OK, but I don't think that really addresses the question of how it's treated within set theory. (Also I similarly find setting up a precedence for and vs. or to be perverse - throwing in some parentheses just seems so much saner.)

Comment: @Ruy Yep.  That's my background.  I've debugged a machine generated C++ parser by hand.  I've also discovered original logical errors in the C++ language standard by mentally processing it, statement by statement.  I have a strange mind.  I gut hung up on things that other people "auto-process".

Comment: @NoahSchweber It is interesting (ironic) that logic typically does have a precedence distinction between $\land$ and $\lor ,$ which are (AFAIK) otherwise indistinguishable  from $\cap$ and $\cup$.

Comment: @StevenThomasHatton Does it? I've certainly never seen expressions like "$A\wedge B\vee C$" used seriously before. (Note that on the CS side we don't have the same "notational duality" between & and |, so the precedence rule looks less symmetric - this might make it more palatable.)

Comment: @NoahSchweber It's not particularly ethical to omit the parentheses, but http://intrologic.stanford.edu/glossary/operator_precedence.html

Comment: @StevenThomasHatton I've never seen that actually used and I strongly dislike it. Of course opinions will vary, but to me using parentheses just increase readability and remove possible confusion - I see no reason *not* to use them, especially given that we can always translate from a "precedence-based" expression to a "fully-parenthesized" expression.